# MonoTouch: how to select initial view from TabBarController's multiple views

Tags: view, xamarin.ios, tabbarcontroller

I have 5 TabBar views... how do I select which view appears when the app first starts? (I have some computations using data that is null at app start time).  The app crashes BEFORE it even gets to FinishedLaunching!  And how does it determine which view is going to be the first one?

One previous answer I got suggested tabBarController.SelectedIndex = 0;  (I'm using MonoTouch)
but didn't tell me where to place it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var u = new UIViewController[]
{
   tab1,
   tab2,
   tab3,
   tab4,
   tab5,
};

this.ViewControllers = u;
this.SelectedViewController = tab1;
```

I typically sub-class the UITabBarController and add the code above in the ViewDidAppear method that I override.

Comment: Thanks Kevin... I'll give it a try and get back to you.  

I do have one q: where does this code go?

I'm new at MonoTouch, so please bear with me... I'm sure I'll have more questions if I run into problems.

Comment: Ignore the lame question re: where does it go!

Comment: Hmmm.. I built this with IB... I would guess tab1, tab2, etc. refer to the name that's displayed in the TabBar itself?  Are they strings, or?  Do you have an actual example of working code?

Comment: No the tab1-tab5 are UIViewControllers that manage the different views that the tabs represent.  Checkout http://MonoTouch.info and do a search for UITabViewController to see some examples.

Answer (score 1):

You should create your view controllers in ViewDidLoad of the UITabBarController, not in the ViewDidAppear. I use the code below (first part is in your AppDelegate class):

```
    // WARNING: Do not make these variables local. MonoTouch will loose the reference to them!
    private UIWindow _mainWindow;
    private MainTabBarController _mainTabBarController;

    public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
    {
        _mainWindow = new UIWindow(UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);
        _mainTabBarController = new MainTabBarController();
        _mainWindow.AddSubview(_mainTabBarController.View);
        _mainWindow.MakeKeyAndVisible ();
        return true;
    }
```

Your MainTabBarController class should look like this:

```
public class MainTabBarController : UITabBarController
{
    public override void ViewDidLoad ()
    {
        ViewControllers = new UIViewController[]
        {
            new ViewControllerTab1(),
            new ViewControllerTab2(),
            new ViewControllerTab3(),
            new ViewControllerTab4(),
            new ViewControllerTab5()
        };
        SelectedIndex = 2;
    }
}
```

This will show Tab3 (with index 2) at startup.

ViewControllerTab1 etc. are classes derived from eg. UIViewController or UINavigationController which implement their user interface in their own ViewDidLoad()

Comment: Little note: you *must* call base.ViewDidLoad here, mustn't you?

Comment: I don't think you have to call base.ViewDidLoad here. Apple's documentation for the UIViewController does not tell this is required. When it is required Apple specifies this (e.g. for viewWillAppear: "If you override this method, you must call super at some point in your implementation"). But I just started iPhone programming, so I'm definitely not an expert in this.