# UITabBarController as RootViewController in MonoTouch

Tags: iphone, mono, xamarin.ios, uitabbarcontroller, xib

I have a HomeScreen with a UITabBarController that i want to set as RootViewController, but when i do it i have following error

```
MonoTouch.Foundation.MonoTouchException has been thrown:

Objective-C exception thrown.  Name: NSUnknownKeyException Reason: [<UIApplication 0xc82d330> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key tabBarController.

MonoTouch.Foundation.MonoTouchException: Objective-C exception thrown.  Name: NSUnknownKeyException Reason: [<UIApplication 0xc82d330> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key tabBarController.
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication:UIApplicationMain (int,string[],intptr,intptr)
  at MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.String principalClassName, System.String delegateClassName) [0x0004c] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:38
  at Test.Application.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in /Users/merqurio/Projects/Test/Test/Main.cs:17
```

I have also  set Nib Name with same XIB name of File's Owner.

This is my project example. [Click Here to Download Project](http://www.merqurio.net/download/test/test.zip)

Answer (score 1):

You have to set Viewcontrollers programmatically....like following

```
-(id)init {

   self = [super init];
    if (self) {


        HomePageViewController *homePageViewController = [[HomePageViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"HomePageViewController" bundle:nil];
        WorkoutOfTheDayViewController *workoutOfTheDayViewController = [[WorkoutOfTheDayViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"WorkoutOfTheDayViewController" bundle:nil];
        ScheduleViewController *scheduleViewController = [[ScheduleViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ScheduleViewController" bundle:nil];
        TrackingViewController *trackingViewController = [[TrackingViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"TrackingViewController" bundle:nil];

        UINavigationController *navHome = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:homePageViewController];
        UINavigationController *navWorkOut = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:workoutOfTheDayViewController];
        UINavigationController *navSchedule = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:scheduleViewController];
        UINavigationController *navTrack = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:trackingViewController];

        homePageViewController.tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Home" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"home.png"] tag:0];
        workoutOfTheDayViewController.tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Log WOD" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"wod.png"] tag:1];
        scheduleViewController.tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Schedule" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"schedule.png"] tag:2];
        trackingViewController.tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Tracking" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tracking.png"] tag:3];


        self.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:navHome,navWorkOut,navSchedule,navTrack, nil];

    }
    return self;
}
```

create one separate class as `UITabbarcontroller`...

then inside of `Appdelegate.h`

```
self.window.rootViewController = [[MainTabBarController alloc]init];
```

Comment: The problem is not that the view controller is not set. The class is not "compatible". According to the log, the problem is "this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key tabBarController". Thus there is a call to set the root view controller.

Answer (score 0):

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
{
    _mainWindow = new UIWindow(UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);
    _mainTabBarController = new MainTabBarController();
    _mainWindow.AddSubview(_mainTabBarController.View);
    _mainWindow.MakeKeyAndVisible ();
    window.RootViewController = _mainTabBarController.View;
    return true;
}
```

and `MainTabBarController` like bellow..

```
public class MainTabBarController : UITabBarController
{
    public override void ViewDidLoad ()
    {
        ViewControllers = new UIViewController[]
        {
            new ViewControllerTab1(),
            new ViewControllerTab2(),
            new ViewControllerTab3(),
            new ViewControllerTab4(),
            new ViewControllerTab5()
        };

    }
}
```

for more info see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4565153/monotouch-how-to-select-initial-view-from-tabbarcontrollers-multiple-views)

Comment: hey see the answer in which create tabbar with bunch of view and after add as a subview of window..